# Outlook: Saving a TFS-PBI with new extension locks the PBI

Tags: c#, tfs, outlook

I'm trying create a new button in outlook, which looks for a task ID, gets the connected PBI and adds the mailitem as attachment.

Quite simple:

```
public void mnuAttachToPBI_Clicked(Office.IRibbonControl control)
{

    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Selection sel = Global.CurrentApplication.ActiveExplorer().Selection;

    if (sel != null && sel.Count > 0)
    {
        string subj;
        foreach (MailItem mailItem in sel)
        {
            subj = mailItem.Subject.Substring(mailItem.Subject.IndexOf('['));
            subj = subj.Substring(0, subj.IndexOf(']'));
            subj = subj.Replace("[", String.Empty);
            subj = subj.Replace("]", string.Empty);
            int taskId;
            if (Int32.TryParse(subj, out taskId))
            {
                WorkItem wi = TfsHandler.GetPbi(taskId);
                if (wi != null)
                {
                    string fileName = Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars().Aggregate(mailItem.Subject + ".msg", (current, c) => current.Replace(c.ToString(), "_"));
                    string path = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), fileName);

                    mailItem.SaveAs(path, OlSaveAsType.olMSG);
                    wi.Attachments.Add(new Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.Attachment(path));
                    wi.Save();
                    wi.Close();
                    File.Delete(path);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The static TFS Handler Class looks like this:

```
private static List<WorkItem> _allWorkItems;

private const string ITEM_TYPE_NAME_PBI = "PBI";
private const string ITEM_TYPE_NAME_TASK = "Task";

private static List<WorkItem> AllWorkItems
{
    get
    {
        if (_allWorkItems == null)
        {
            WorkItemCollection wc = new WorkItemStore(TFS_SRV).Query(
                    " SELECT [System.Id], [System.WorkItemType]," +
                " [System.State], [System.AssignedTo], [System.Title] " +
                " FROM WorkItems");

            _allWorkItems = new List<WorkItem>();
            foreach (WorkItem w in wc)
                _allWorkItems.Add(w);
        }

        return _allWorkItems;
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Gets the PBI, if the workitem is a task id, it checks parents
/// </summary>
/// <param name="workItemId"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
public static WorkItem GetPbi(int workItemId)
{
    WorkItem result = AllWorkItems.FirstOrDefault(f => f.Id == workItemId);

    if (result.Type.Name == ITEM_TYPE_NAME_TASK)
    {
        result = AllWorkItems.FirstOrDefault(f => f.Id == result.WorkItemLinks[0].TargetId);
    }

    return result;
}
```

Works fine: I check, if there is a [ID] in the mailitem title, get the task, if its a task, I get the PBI, save the mail as attachment and add it.

But if I try to open the PBI from outlook, I get:

---

### Team Foundation Error

### Cross-thread operation not valid: Control '' accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created on.

### OK

Since I'm closing AND saving the workitem aka the PBI, I really hoped this would handle such stuff.

I didnt find any good solution for this problem and since I'm quite a beginner, I dont have the knowledge to see the problem myself.

Is there a mistake from my site or is my approach not possible at all?

Comment: Why not just use Team Companion? Does it not have this functionality built in?

Comment: Hm thanks, I created my own Set of TFS-Facades, which allow me to abstract the whole mudding in WiLINQ etc. But I will give TeamCompanion a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are going to have to do some threading work. When you click the button in Outlook, outlook spawns a new thread that is trying to access the cashed work items that are on a separate threas (one that was created when you first called the property.

You will likely need to create your own background thread context that owns the data. Then when the button is clicked you can marshal your context over to the same thread context to execute and pass the data back.

Its a pain but that's Outlook development...

Comment: Teamlook+Outlook+VS TFS Combination = Pain, but atm it's working fine. But I think your approach wird be the solution for this.